# LifeRay devStudio can't access BaseGetDataResourceImpl to create object from there why?

Tags: java, liferay

GetDataResourceImpl extends BaseGetDataResourceImp

i can'i access this class BaseGetDataResourceImp to create object ?

```
`package com.lr.IST.Get.Data.internal.resource.v1_0_0;

import com.lr.IST.Get.Data.resource.v1_0_0.GetDataResource;

import org.osgi.service.component.annotations.Component;
import org.osgi.service.component.annotations.ServiceScope;

/**
 * @author abdallateef
 */
@Component(
properties = "OSGI-INF/liferay/rest/v1_0_0/get-data.properties",
scope = ServiceScope.PROTOTYPE, service = GetDataResource.class
)
public class GetDataResourceImpl extends BaseGetDataResourceImpl {


}`
```

this code come from yaml file

```
components:
    schemas:
        GetDataModule:
            type: object
            properties:
              name:
                type: string
              counter:
                type: integer
                format: int64
        GetDataResponse:
          type: array
          items:
            type: object
            properties:
              name:
                type: string
              counter:
                type: integer
paths:
    "/getData":
        post:
            operationId: getData
            tags: [ "GetDataResponse" ]
            description: OK
            requestBody:
                content:
                    application/json:
                        schema:
                            $ref: '#/components/schemas/GetDataModule'
                    application/xml:
                        schema:
                            $ref: '#/components/schemas/GetDataModule'
            responses:
                '200':
                    description: OK
                    content:
                        application/json:
                            schema:
                 $ref: '#/components/schemas/GetDataResponse'
                        application/xml: 
                            schema:
                 $ref: '#/components/schemas/GetDataResponse'
```

what is wrong ?

just comment I have added some code and modified several parts of it, but the post cannot be submitted. It is fine if this message appears when asking a new question, but it appears when I am trying to resubmit my edited post.